# Errors while installing IO (language)

Tags: macos, iolanguage

I am trying to install IO on a macbook pro but am stuck at the following:

> Linking CXX shared library _build/dll/libIoObjcBridge.dylib ld:
>   library not found for -lIoSocket collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[2]: *** [addons/ObjcBridge/_build/dll/libIoObjcBridge.dylib]
>
>   Error 1 make[1]: ***
>   [addons/ObjcBridge/CMakeFiles/IoObjcBridge.dir/all] Error 2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `libevent`. I did it with Homebrew.